# How can I update marker location in real time when dragging in Google Map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

When I drag the marker in Google Map, I want to update the marker location in realtime and show it in text up the marker.
Now I can just update marker location when end the dragging by implement `void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker)`, but can't update the location when I am dragging the marker in map.
So how can I update or know marker location when I am dragging it in map?

Comment: So what's wrong with using `onMarkerDrag` instead of `onMarkerDragEnd`?

Comment: I try to use `onMarkerDrag` instead of `onMarkerDragEnd` ever, but I forgot to `showInfoWindow` to update the snippet, so I thought the marker location is not updated. In fact, the marker location is updated. How silly of me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use onMarkerDrag() for that..See the below given example..

```
marker=Mmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentpos)
                .title("Draggable Marker")
                .snippet("Long press and move the marker if needed.")
                .draggable(true)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mark_start)));
        Mmap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Marker", "Dragging");
                            LatLng markerLocation = marker.getPosition();
                            Log.d("MarkerPosition", markerLocation.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LatLng markerLocation = marker.getPosition();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, markerLocation.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Marker", "finished");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Marker", "Started");

            }
        });
```