# How can I update location when I drag marker current location to another location?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

Update location when I drag my location pointer to another place. And It shows on marker title like the current location. Currently, It is showing marker title but shows where the marker is dropped location.

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener {

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
TextView add;
Button button;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
String getbuildingname,locality,subLocality,current_state,current_country,postal_code;
double longitude,latitude;
double last_longitude,last_latitude;
private GoogleMap mMap;
String addrs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    add = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_location);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    add_location();


}
// Map ready method
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
}
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(MapActivity.this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }
     //Showing Current Location Marker on Map
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    assert locationManager != null;
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    assert provider != null;
    Location locations = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    List<String> providerList = locationManager.getAllProviders();
    if (null != locations && providerList.size() > 0) {
        longitude = locations.getLongitude();
        latitude = locations.getLatitude();

        // Geo Coder access location via lat and long
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
                    longitude, 1);
            if (null != listAddresses && listAddresses.size() > 0) {
                getbuildingname = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                locality = listAddresses.get(0).getLocality(); 
                subLocality = listAddresses.get(0).getSubLocality();  
                current_state = listAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea();  
                current_country = listAddresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                postal_code = listAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode();  
                markerOptions.title(""+latLng+","+subLocality+"," + locality + "," +
                        current_state + "," + current_country + "," + postal_code);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                this);
    }
}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}
public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                }
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return;
    }
}
// Click Listener with data insertion
private void add_location(){

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
            String lng = String.valueOf(longitude);
            addrs = "Latitude - "+lat+" , "+"Longitude - "+lng+"\nAddress - "+getbuildingname;
            add.setText(addrs);
            add.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }
    });
}

// New Methods
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    marker.setDraggable(true);
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    last_latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
    last_longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

}
```

I can get my current location and can drag marker.

There is no error but I have no idea how can I update location ?

Comment: See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829195/google-maps-error-markers-position-is-not-updated-after-drag and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590050/how-can-i-update-marker-location-in-real-time-when-dragging-in-google-map-v2

Answer (score 0):

You should call `marker.getPosition()` in your `onMarkerDrag` method to get the marker's current location while it's being dragged. (I understood this is what you want to do, but please correct me if wrong).

For reference, Google's documentation on [marker drag events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker#marker_drag_events) states:

> You can use an
>   [OnMarkerDragListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener.html)
>   to listen for drag events on a marker. To set this listener on the
>   map, call [GoogleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setOnMarkerDragListener(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener)).
>
> When a marker is dragged, onMarkerDragStart(Marker) is called
>   initially. While the marker is being dragged, onMarkerDrag(Marker) is
>   called constantly. At the end of the drag onMarkerDragEnd(Marker) is
>   called. You can get the position of the marker at any time by calling
>   Marker.getPosition().

Hope this helps you.